# wrong auth type while working with rails 3.1.0 and devise (win7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i try to setup a mailer for a rails 3 application and devise. The app is in development progress. The app should send an email for "i have forgot my password". In `config/enviroment/development` i added:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

###

```
require 'tlsmail'

Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {

  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "tatutest.com",
  :tls => true,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "****@gmail.com",
  :password => "****"

}
```

In `config/initializers/devise` i changed the config.mailer_sender in:

```
config.mailer_sender = "****@gmail.com" (like :user_name in development)
```

when i try to send an email over the view i get the error:

```
ArgumentError in Devise::PasswordsController#create 
wrong auth type tatutest
```

I don't know whether it is important but the domain "tatutest.com" doesn't exists!

Hope you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

your action_mailer config is how rails will talk to the program that will actually send the emails.

if it is set up to try and access a mailing-program on a domain that does not exist... well it won't work. You have to point action_mailer at a *real* mail program. For development environment - this will be whatever email program you use on your own computer.